# API works in IntelliJ, but in Android Studio not

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am working on a weather application for a school project (Android application, Java) in Android Studio.

```
private String requestData(String city) throws Exception {
    String url = buildURL(city);
    URL obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO improve ErrorHandling
        throw new Exception("URL Problem");
    }
    HttpURLConnection con;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()); //after this row the code is not executed in Android Studio
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO improve ErrorHandling
        System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

This code works perfect in IntelliJ, it returns the answer from the API, but when I want to use it in my Android project nothing happens and after the row "InputStreamReader sir = new...." my code is not executed, but I become no exception.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Android, network operations must be executed in background thread. You can see background tasks in Android.

Comment: Don't catch an exception and then rethrow a new exception containing no information. Just remove your try/catches completely.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will try out!